# Using AJAX to include html on other web sites and retrieve user data

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

Would the following work? And I would like to know of there is a better way to do this if anyone has any ideas?

1. Page loads ajax script file from another site/domain
2. User fills in a form on the page and submits it via JSON/AJAX back to the original site/domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The related question [Cross-domain ajax - would this method work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392124/cross-domain-ajax-would-this-method-work) discusses the use of iframes to do cross domain Ajax.  The accepted answer has a link to [Cross domain communication with iframes](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes), a post about how to communicate across domains using an iframe in a page.  You can use one of the "hacks" there (spawning new iframes in the same domain, monitoring state, etc). to accomplish what you are trying to do.